# When I execute a CAML Query in an event list handler, I don't get all the list fields

Tags: sharepoint, event-handling

When I execute a CAML Query in a list event handler, the query executes against the current view for the list.  I have certain fields that I need to query regardless of the view - how do I get the "allitems" view or equivalent for the actual list.

Answer (score 0):

Look for SPList.DefaultView

There you can get the ViewFields property and see what fields are being returned.